# How to run Jolokia on Intelliji

Tags: java, jolokia

I'm tried to custom Jolokia and run it in Intelliji, but seem didn't work.
Java Application give error: Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing: C:\Users\Desktop\jolokia-1.7.2\jolokia-1.7.2\agent\jvm\target\classes
But if running file jar after complie, it still work.
Anyone can help me out

.

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jolokia/jolokia-agent-jvm/2.0.1/jolokia-agent-jvm-2.0.1-javaagent.jar

Note `-javaagent.jar` is important, which is the runnable jar. For Jolokia 1.x, you'd have needed `jolokia-jvm-1.x.y-agent.jar` but with some releasing issue with Jolokia, the standalone jars weren't available for some versions such as 1.7.2.